# Mongo DB $push object wraps it in an array first

Tags: javascript, mongodb

When I use $push in mongodb, the expected outcome turns out differently. It actually wraps the object I want to push in an array. This is problematic because I'd have to map over the result just to extract it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**My Mongo Query**

```
const pushAction = {
    $push: {
      cart: {
        id: itemId,
        quantity: quantity
      }
    }
  }

  // Add item to user's cart
  User.update({_id: userId}, pushAction, (err, success) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(422).json({'error': 'There was a problem adding the item to your cart.'});
    }
    if (success) {
      // Find user and return the cart
      User.findOne({_id: userId}, {cart: 1}, (err, user) => {
        res.status(200).json({'message': 'The item was successfully added to your cart.', cart: user.cart});
      })
    }
  });
```

**User Schema**

```
// Define User Model
const userSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: {
    type: Schema.Types.String,
    required: true
  },
  lastName: {
    type: Schema.Types.String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: Schema.Types.String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: Schema.Types.String,
    required: true
  },
  cart: {
    type: Schema.Types.Array
  },
  dateCreated: {
    type: Schema.Types.Date,
    default: Date.now,
    required: true
  },
  dateUpdated: [
    {
      date: {
        type: Schema.Types.Date
      },
      details: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId
      }
    }
  ],
  verified: {
    type: Schema.Types.Boolean,
    required: true
  },
  role: {
    type: Schema.Types.String,
    default: ROLES_BASIC_USER
  }
});
```

**Expected Outcome**

```
"cart" : [ 
    {
        "id" : "587b6b69799ad7ff650edbb5",
        "quantity" : 1
    }, 
    {
        "id" : "587b6b69799ad7ff650edbb5",
        "quantity" : 1
    }, 
    {
        "id" : "587b6b69799ad7ff650edbb5",
        "quantity" : 1
    }
],
```

**Actual Result**

```
"cart" : [ 
        [ 
            {
                "id" : "587b6b69799ad7ff650edbb5",
                "quantity" : 1
            }
        ], 
        [ 
            {
                "id" : "587b6b69799ad7ff650edbb5",
                "quantity" : 1
            }
        ], 
        [ 
            {
                "id" : "587b6b69799ad7ff650edbb5",
                "quantity" : 1
            }
        ]
    ]
```

Comment: i think the issue is in your schema... Can you post your schema..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Define User Model
const userSchema = new Schema({
  firstName: {
    type: Schema.Types.String,
    required: true
  },
  lastName: {
    type: Schema.Types.String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: Schema.Types.String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: Schema.Types.String,
    required: true
  },
  cart:[ {
    id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    quantity: Number 
  }],
  dateCreated: {
    type: Schema.Types.Date,
    default: Date.now,
    required: true
  },
  dateUpdated: [
    {
      date: {
        type: Schema.Types.Date
      },
      details: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId
      }
    }
  ],
  verified: {
    type: Schema.Types.Boolean,
    required: true
  },
  role: {
    type: Schema.Types.String,
    default: ROLES_BASIC_USER
  }
});
```

Comment: Plain code without any explanation what was wrong is always bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing pushAction as follows:

```
const pushAction = {
    $push: {
        cart: { $each: [ {id: itemId, quantity: quantity } ] }
    }
}
```

Clean existing items in `cart` field before trying this.
If it still fails then the issue might be with the schema.

Comment: yeah error still occurs even after changing the query. I've updated my question above with the schema :)

Comment: Change your schema for cart to `cart: [{ id: Schema.Types.ObjectId, quantity: Number }]` and then try your query (clear data before testing). It should work.